# How to interact with Windows GUI through Selenium

Tags: java, user-interface, firefox, selenium, selenium-rc

My selenium based test-suite works fine while I was controlling just the browser.

A new test case I need to add into the suite which requires interacting with Windows Browse/Upload file explorer after selenium has clicked upload button in under test page on the browser.

I couldn't find anything in Selenium RC documents about how to write filename  in the (windows GUI) browse's "file name" field  and click (windows GUI)Open button. Any ideas? Thanks!

Just to let you know in advance.
The test-suite executes test on 100s of remote machines concurrently. So auto-it-script workaround won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium RC supports file upload, but not using the browser mechanism directly.  Check out the `AttachFile()` method, which takes a URL for the file and downloads it to the browser machine before then uploading it to the application.